# How to chain the command 'rotate xticklabels' to seaborn plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I was learning the pandas piping method with seaborn plots:
Most of the things are easily easily chained in one-liner, but I was having 
difficulty piping the `xticklabel rotations`.

How to do so?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
names = ['mpg','cylinders', 'displacement','horsepower','weight',
         'acceleration','model_year', 'origin', 'car_name']

url = "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data"
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep='\s+', names=names)
```

## Plot

```
g = ( df.pipe((sns.factorplot, 'data'), x='model_year', y='mpg')
)

for ax in g.axes.flat: 
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
```

Required skeleton:

```
( df.pipe((sns.factorplot, 'data'), x='model_year', y='mpg')
.set(xlim=(0,90), ylim=(0,80))
.set (xticklabel_rotation = 45)
)
```

Is this possible?

Required Image:
[image]

But I am getting:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Instead of `.set(xticklabel_rotation = 45)` you wanted `.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)`

```
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns
names = ['mpg','cylinders', 'displacement','horsepower','weight',
         'acceleration','model_year', 'origin', 'car_name']

url = "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data"
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep='\s+', names=names)

(df.pipe((sns.factorplot, 'data'), x='model_year', y='mpg')
.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
)
```

This gave me:

[image]

Comment: Can we also set xlim and ylim? `.set(xlim=(70,80))` gives very weird result in this case.

Comment: Yes, though when plotting the x-values aren't represented as you'd expect. The first value (70) is plotted at ```x=0```. There are then 12 more unique years, plotted at ```x=1```, ```x=2```, ```x=3``` etc. So, to get what you desired earlier you'd use ```.set(xlim=(-0.5, 12.5), ylim=(0,80))```